# How long is "temporary" for the Google remove URL tool?

Tags: google-search-console

Google Search Console says...

> **Remove URLs**
>   Temporarily remove URLs that you own from search results. To remove content permanently, you must remove or update the source page. [More information.](https://www.google.com/support/webmasters/answer/59819)
>   <kbd>Temporarily Hide</kbd>

How long is "temporary"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Temporarily removal lasts for 90 days since the request.

**EDIT** : Official link -  https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1663419?hl=en